# Does CISCO ASA configuration "access-list" protocol name "ip" includes both "tcp" and "udp"?

Tags: cisco, asa, cisco-ios, pix

I have several lines and I wonder if some are shadowed due to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, but it doesnt include protocols like gre etc, if you need vpn tunnels or something similar

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Cisco ASA command "access-list 101 extended permit ip host 1.1.1.1 host 2.2.2.2" permits all 256 IPv4 protocols from 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2, including tcp, udp, and gre (which is protocol 47).

Answer (score 1):

IP, TCP, UDP, ICMP, GRE, IGRP all use IP at the Network Layer.  The IP statement does include all layer 3 protocols.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful while defining access lists.
Choosing ip will cover both tcp and udp so to prevent shadowing, you should order the ACL carefully, not put the ip ACL on top.